# Apache refuses to start on any port

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I can't seem to get Apache to start on any port.  I'm always getting the error:

```
apache2(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

I checked to make sure that nothing is running on port 80 with `netstat -plant|grep 80` and I even ran `sudo nc -l 80` with no problems just to be certain.  I thought maybe it might be a permissions thing (it shouldn't since it should be starting from an initscript), so I changed the listening port for Apache to 8080, and got the same error except on port 8080 (and nothing is running on that port either).  I even tried setting `ports.conf` to have `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` and even `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080` and still more or less the same error except for showing the corresponding address and port.

I should note that I'm on Debian Unstable.

At this point, I'm at a loss for what else to check.

Comment: Check if SELinux or something similar is on, by runnning `sestatus` or `getenforce`.

Comment: `root@debian:/home/mohsen/Downloads# netstat -atupn |egrep :80 |egrep LISTEN`                                                               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5261/apache2

Comment: or `nmap localhost`

Comment: I don't have SELinux on this machine, so that shouldn't be an issue.  That netstat command returns nothing.  And nmap doesn't show port 80 as even being open.

Comment: I wonder what your Apache startup script looks like?  Can you post it?  Let's just say for the sake of the argument that the script happened to have a bug that would start httpd twice ?

Comment: Try `strace -f` on your startup.

Comment: Maybe also check those two ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160339/starting-apache-fails-could-not-bind-to-address-0-0-0-080?rq=1) / [2](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=105457)) other discussions on the issue if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks illuminÉ, but neither of those helped. @unixhacker2010 The start up script is just stock Debian start up script for Apache, but I posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/uHSg7fpv).  I also disabled all the sites except for the default one, which is mostly just right from the package, and I've posted that [here](http://pastebin.com/GCeXy1EQ).  I couldn't figure out what to look for from the strace output, but I have that [here](http://ubuntuone.com/0DjJ2lqkaEDMkwx8fcCddu).

Comment: Are you using Virtual hosts?

Comment: `apachectl -S` shows a binding/listen for port 80 two times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your strace file, here is your problem:

```
[pid 23020] setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(5, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [0], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(5, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] bind(5, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(80), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0
[pid 23020] listen(5, 511)              = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(7, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(7, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(7, SOL_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, [0], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] setsockopt(7, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 23020] bind(7, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(80), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
[pid 23020] write(2, "(98)Address already in use: AH00"..., 82(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
) = 82
```

You'll notice `bind` is being called *twice*. The first time it works. The second time, it fails because the address is already in use—which it is, because it was just bound.

I have confirmed on my apache config (Apache 2.4 on Debian testing/unstable) that I can make this happen by having `Listen 80` in the config twice. I suspect you've done the same, or something very similar.

Comment: Even without the strace the duple/multiple listen lines on same port has bitten me too.

Comment: This looks like IPv6 port 80 being bound twice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem might be related to attempting to bind IPV6 address instead of IPV4. Example Apache is trying to bind to ::1 and 127.0.0.1, since you don't have IPv6 configured - it attempts to bind do 127.0.0.1 twice. 
Solutions:

- check if localhosts resolves to IPv4 IP (getent hosts localhost)
- check /etc/hosts and remove any IPv6 adresses if you are not using IPv6 (especially localhost one)

If you are not able to update `/etc/hosts` - change `httpd.conf` or `ports.conf` to bind to IP, rather then name (Listen 127.0.0.1:80).

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the error message that Apache is trying to bind using IPv6. Does your host have IPv6 enabled?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please don't add comments as answers. Use actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.